# how to use Shared preferences in quiz

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I'm facing a problem with shared preferences..

In my application im using shared preference for saving the quiz answers..

I have tried. Its works fine when i came to perivous question..But my problem is..

When 1st question comes user choose a answer and goes for 2nd question, here also user will choose the answer and goes for 3rd question like wise process moves.. When user comes back for perivous question (2nd question), here users answer checks the button correctly and when user goes for next by this time the answer does not checks correctly... what mistaken i have done?

Please point out me.. and give a solution how to get that?  Thanks a lot in advance..

Sorry for my bad english..

Here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RadioGroup btn_practicerg;
    RadioButton btn_practice1;
    RadioButton btn_practice2;
    RadioButton btn_practice3;
    RadioButton btn_practice4;
    RadioGroup radioButton;
    TextView quetxt;
    Button next;
    Button previous;
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    int checkedIndex;
    int num = 1;
    private ArrayList<String> answ1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> ques1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_practicerg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
        btn_practice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB1);
        btn_practice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB2);
        btn_practice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB3);
        btn_practice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RB4);
        quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accbtn);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LoadQuestions();
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedId = btn_practicerg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                RadioButton radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                checkedIndex = btn_practicerg.indexOfChild(radioSexButton);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, radioSexButton.getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (i == ques1.size() - 1) {
                    showAlert();
                } else {

                    ++i;
                    ++num;
                    TextView quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
                    quetxt.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(i));

                    ++k;
                    btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 0));
                    btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 1));
                    btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 2));
                    btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 3));
                    btn_practicerg.clearCheck();

                    SavePreferences(String.valueOf(num), checkedIndex);

                }
            }

            private void showAlert() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        Button previousbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accbtn);
        previousbtn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                --i;
                --num;
                TextView quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
                quetxt.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(i));

                --k;
                btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 0));
                btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 1));
                btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 2));
                btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 3));

                LoadPreferences();
            }
        });

    }

    private void LoadQuestions() {
        ques1.add("whats the name?");
        ques1.add("whats place?");
        ques1.add("whats the favourite?");
        ques1.add("whats the game?");
        ques1.add("whats the time?");

        answ1.add("A");
        answ1.add("B");
        answ1.add("C");
        answ1.add("D");
        answ1.add("MDU");
        answ1.add("MS");
        answ1.add("CHE");
        answ1.add("POND");
        answ1.add("1");
        answ1.add("2");
        answ1.add("3");
        answ1.add("4");
        answ1.add("VB");
        answ1.add("TENN");
        answ1.add("HOC");
        answ1.add("CRI");
        answ1.add("11");
        answ1.add("12");
        answ1.add("13");
        answ1.add("14");

        quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
        quetxt.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(i));

        btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(0));
        btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(1));
        btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(2));
        btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(3));
    }

    private void SavePreferences(String key, int value) {
        int quest = (Integer.parseInt(key)) - 1;
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF",
                0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(String.valueOf(quest), value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void LoadPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences getProgramPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        int savedRadioIndex = getProgramPrefs.getInt(String.valueOf(num), -1);

        System.out.println("SavedRadioIndex" + savedRadioIndex);
        RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton) btn_practicerg
                .getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
        savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group
                    .findViewById(checkedId);
            checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            System.out.println("checkedIndex" + checkedIndex);
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to save such data in preferences. It's better to save this data in database if you want to get data when application is finished and then started again. But in situation like this you can store data in some object in activity like this:

```
public class Question {
private int id;
private String question;
private List<Answer> possibleAnswers;
private int correctAnswerId;
private String userAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging for watching the values of "quest" variable on SavePreferences method? There're two unnecessary casts from String to int and from int to String again, maybe this can be the problem depending on the values of "key" variable.

You should try to use "key" variable directly as a key for editor without casting.

The rest of the function seems correct.

**EDIT**
What i'm saying is that maybe there's a problem on this cast, but i'm not sure.

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```